# How to save and load a list again?

Tags: ios, swift, save, load

I'm trying to code a simple app with a table view to show some to do things. (In this case, it is called "Grails" / things I want to buy).

I did everything about the table view, and the input and so on, and the only thing I need to do, is to save and load all the information again. But I don't know how.

This is my code on the first view Controller:

```
import UIKit

var list = ["Nike Air Jordan 1 x Off White", "Balenciaga Speed Trainers", "Gucci Snake Sneakers", "Goyard Card Holder"]

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return list.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
            list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        myTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

---

And the second view controller looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any) {
        if (input.text != "") {
            list.append(input.text!)
            input.text = ""
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Now the code looks like this, but i can't add any new items to the list from the button on the second view controller?

import UIKit

var list = ["Nike Air Jordan 1 x Off White", "Balenciaga Speed Trainers", "Gucci Snake Sneakers", "Goyard Card Holder"]

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (list.count)
}

func updateData() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(list, forKey: "list")
    myTableView.reloadData()
}

//LOADING THE DATA AGAIN
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let storedList = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "list")
    {
        list = storedList as! [String]
    }
    else
    {
        print("No list previously stored")
    }
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = list[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return true
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let item = list[sourceIndexPath.row]
    list.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    list.insert(item, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}

@IBAction func edit(_ sender: Any)
{
    myTableView.isEditing = !myTableView.isEditing

    switch myTableView.isEditing {
    case true:
        editButtonItem.title = "Done"
    case false:
        editButtonItem.title = "Edit"
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    {
        list.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        updateData()
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    updateData()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Is the first list showing as intended? I mean, the only problem is the update or do you have issues from the very beginning? If so, please post the entire code.  On the other hand, if this is your **entire** code then your problem is you're not setting your tableview `delegate`

Comment: Im pretty much a newbie, ahah. But this is the entire code, and then there is the viewDidLoad and didReceiveMemoryWarning functions in the end as they were in the beginning.

The list is showed as it should, and is working perfectly fine. I can add and delete from it as i want to. I just need to know how to save and load the data when the app reopen. :)

Comment: Ahh you see, then that's the real question (you needed to be more specific). There are several approach to handle this, if you're data is small (< 1 Mb) then `UserDefaults.standard` is the quickiest and easiest way to go. If it's not, then you must consider reading more about _CoreData_ or even using a `pod` for it such as Realm

Comment: Thank you! But then my question is; how can i use UserDefaults in this case?

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes and i'll reply with a formatted response down below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as stated in the comments above you may very well use `UserDefaults.standard` in this case since it's a small amount of data you're dealing with. If you want you want to update your data every time it gets updated (add/remove a new item) then you should do some code refactoring to include the *saving* part alongside your `myTableView.reloadData()`. Here's how you do it:

```
func updateData() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(list, forKey: "list")
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then you'll calling `updateData()` everywhere you were calling `myTableView.reloadData()` (just so i made myself clear: replace it since the method already includes the *reload* part). That's it for the saving part. Now you must handle the *loading*, usually you'd do this in the `AppDelegate` class in the `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` method but for simplicity sake let's just teach you how to do it inside you're already missing `viewDidLoad()` method in the *FirstViewController* class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let storedList = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "list") {
        list = storedList as! [String] 
    } else {
        print("No list previously stored")
    }
}
```

If any previous `list` was stored, then replace the value. Otherwise it prints the message just as a confirmation (you could delete it in the future if you want, in order to keep the console log for useful stuff).

One final thing i must say is that i did a *Force casting* since with the `storedList` since i knew for a fact it was a `String` array but you should be careful very careful using `as!`. Always perform safe casting since in case of failure you're app will crash.

Comment: Im feeling very stupid right now. Sorry if I'm wasting your time, but I really appreciate it!

Now, i think i did as you said, and I kinda understood it.

But now, nothing is adding, when i click the add button on my secondViewController.

Comment: Mm everything looks fine in your _FirstViewController_, is that the entire _SecondViewController_ code?

Comment: Everything about the adding and so on worked perfectly, and still do if i change it back. So I think its the first one. (Made a post called "How to make the cancel button in alert cancel the action" where i posted my secondViewController code, if you would take a look please.) :D

Comment: Link of that please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621078/how-to-make-the-cancel-button-in-alert-cancel-the-action

Comment: Upload the project to a github repo so i can clone it and see for myself all the wiring. Paste the link here when you're done and i'll take a look

Comment: FINALLY! Didn't know how to use GitHub, but think i nailed it. Here is the link: https://github.com/Sejezebbe/GRAILS 

(Its hard to understand all of the english programming words, when you are just a teenager from Denmark!)

Comment: I went the extra mile for this 15 points: I just solved the problem (you had something bad wired in your storyboard) but now github won't let me push the changes. You have to either invite me or make the repo public.

Comment: Thank you. I invited you know. This is your invite link: https://github.com/Sejezebbe/GRAILS/invitations

Comment: Pushed now. Please check.

Comment: You can thank me by awarding me the points. My answer was correct after all :)