# How to make the cancel button in alert cancel the action?

Tags: swift, alert

I made an alert as you can see, but the app adds the item, no matter if I'm clicking the "NO" button og the "Yes, I'm sure" button when the alert pops up.

My goal is to make the "NO" action, cancel the action so the input won't be added anyway. Can you tell me how to?

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

    @IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)
    {
        createAlert(title: "That's a good grail!", message: "Are you sure you want to add this grail?")

        if (input.text != "")
        {
            list.append(input.text!)
            input.text = ""
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.input.delegate = self
    }

    //HIDE KEYBOARD:
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    //PRESSES RETURN KEY:
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        input.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func createAlert (title:String, message:String)
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        //CREATING OK BUTTON

        let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, I'm sure!", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

            // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
            print("Ok button tapped");

        }
        alertController.addAction(OKAction)

        // Create Cancel button
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No!", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
            print("Cancel button tapped");
        }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Present Dialog message
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The code looks like this now, thanks:

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)
{
    createAlert(title: "That's a good grail!", message: "Are you sure you want to add this grail?")

}



override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.input.delegate = self
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//HIDE KEYBOARD:
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//PRESSES RETURN KEY:
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    input.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


func createAlert (title:String, message:String)
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //CREATING OK BUTTON

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, I'm sure!", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
        print("Ok button tapped");
        if (self.self.input.text != "")
        {
            list.append(self.input.text!)
            self.input.text = ""
        }

    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    // Create Cancel button
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No!", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Cancel button tapped");
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present Dialog message
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see clearly what you are asking for. But if you don't add no code to the cancel action closure, nothing will happen. :)

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough. New at this programming thing. :) Right now i have a list. I can add the item, i typed in the text field to the list / table view, when i push the button. But when i pushed the button i want a alert to pop up, and ask if I'm sure i want to add this item. Right now the alert is popping up, but the same will happen if i press the cancel button, as if i press the ok button.

I want the cancel / "NO" button to cancel the action, so the text WONT be added to the list / table view if I press "NO". :)

Answer (score 0):

simply just put the code for adding the item to the OK closure:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)
{
    createAlert(title: "That's a good grail!", message: "Are you sure you want to add this grail?")
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.input.delegate = self
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//HIDE KEYBOARD:
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//PRESSES RETURN KEY:
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    input.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}


func createAlert (title:String, message:String)
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    //CREATING OK BUTTON

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, I'm sure!", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
     if (input.text != "")
     {
        list.append(input.text!)
        input.text = ""
     }
        print("Ok button tapped");

    }
    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    // Create Cancel button
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "No!", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Cancel button tapped");
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present Dialog message
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the `input.text` anyway in your `addItem(_ :)` method after you show your `UIAlertController`.

So if you want to avoid the `input.text` is added always and only when the OK button is tapped you should include in the closure for the action when you created it and remove it after the presentation of the `UIAlertController`

```
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, I'm sure!", style: .default) { [weak self] _ in

        guard let selfStrong = self else {
            return
        }

        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
        if (selfStrong.input.text != "") {
           selfStrong.list.append(input.text!)
           selfStrong.input.text = ""
        }
}
```

For the cancel button, you don't need any action closure unless you want to do something when the cancel button is tapped too.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not appending the item on click of "Yes, I'm sure" button. Remove the below code inside **@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)** method and put it inside **OKAction** handler block.

```
if (input.text != "")
    {
        list.append(input.text!)
        input.text = ""
    }
```

Do like this:

```
@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: Any)
    {
        createAlert(title: "That's a good grail!", message: "Are you sure you want to add this grail?")


}
```

Inside method: **func createAlert (title:String, message:String)** (put append code here)

```
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes, I'm sure!", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
        print("Ok button tapped");
    if (input.text != "")
    {
        list.append(input.text!)
        input.text = ""
    }
}
```